# Meteor collection insert from input element

Tags: meteor

This code is trying to insert the data from `input` elements on the page into a Meteor Collection `Task1`

I am getting "App is crashing error" because of the `Tasks1.insert` line. Why and how can I fix it?
I need to get the element name and value as the key:value pair for the Document being inserted. Thanks

```
Template.footer.events({
  'click button': function () {
    if ( this.text === "SUBMIT" ) {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      Tasks1.insert({inputs[i].name: inputs[i].value});
    }
  }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inputs[i].name` cannot be used as a key of an object literal, because it's a variable and we can only use strings for defining properties in an object literal.

Like this it should work (it's the most common workaround):

```
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  // First define a variable
  var params = {};

   // Then you can use a variable (or a function) to set the key
  params[inputs[i].name] = inputs[i].value;

  Tasks1.insert(params);
}
```